# Adding a search subform query that allows single-click appendage

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, vba

Let me attempt to explain the layout of my main form. I have a Physician subform which allows for entry into the Physician table. It includes fields like Name, SSN, DOB, etc.

I then *want* a a search form next to this form which allows me to search all Practices that these Physicians may work at. I want to be able to search for practices by select fields like Name, TIN, NPI, etc.

Lastly, I want a form below the Provider subform which lists all practices related to that provider. If someone searches for a practice in the search form, I need to allow them to click to add that practice to the form below so that the Provider and Practice will then be related.

I understand the basic structure of the forms. I'm just not sure if this will require VBA or if I can accomplish it all with some basic queries and relationships.

Comment: It will almost certainly require VBA

Comment: I think you can do most of it with queries, so long as each search field has its own textbox.  So, you'ld have to have 3 textboxes; one for Name, one for TIN and one for NPI.  Then in a query just set the criteria to "LIKE " & [Forms]![MySearchForm]![MySearchField] & "".  You can make this a little slicker if you use VBA and build the query on the fly, because you could just use one textbox for the search parameters and either a radio or checkbox to determine which field you want to search.  You may need asterisks in that LIKE statement, I can't add them without turning into italics.